# Loop through list using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Total js newb here.

Here is the HTML

```
<a href="#" class="dur" id="8.5">Size 8.5</a>
 <div class="product1">
 <ul class="sizeAvail" style="display:none;">   
  <li>8</li>    
  <li>8.5</li>  
  <li>9</li>    
  <li>9.5</li>  
  <li>10</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="product2">
 <ul class="sizeAvail" style="display:none;">   
  <li>8</li>    
  <li>8.5</li>  
  <li>9</li>    
  <li>9.5</li>  
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Here's the 'logic' of what I need...

When the user clicks the Link

Capture the id of that element

Set that as a variable

Loop through li for all ul that have class 'sizeAvail'

If li element matches variable

stop looping and move onto next ul

If ul does not have li that matches variable

set class of container div to 'hide'

This is where I'm at so far...any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" > $(document).ready(
 $(".dur").click(function () {
 var clickedSize = $(this).attr("id");
 $(".sizeAvail").each(function (li,+) {
    alert($(this).text());
 });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Is anything happening if so what

Comment: You should pass a function to `.ready()` method. And `+` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: You should not put "." on id value. Try to use data-id="8.5" or data-size="8.5" and access it with jquery .data('id') or .data('size').

Comment: A jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/eWTRZ/  (not solving anything, just helping you illustrate your current problem).

Comment: I cleaned up the JS, but hopefully it originated as a copy-paste error and wasn't the actual code. if it was the actual code, I may have fixed it with an edit. ;-)

Comment: @BradChristie Actually that was a radical edit, you shouldn't change the code :) I'll rollback.

Comment: @LucasMaus: HTML5 accepts [anything but a space](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute) ;-)

Comment: You are right, I thought my coding pattern was a rule.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/uZTYf/

Here is the jquery I used:

```
$(".dur").click(function () {
    var clickedSize = this.id;
    $(".sizeAvail li").each(function () {
        if($(this).text() == clickedSize) {
            $(this).parent().show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

What you are currently doing is not right as you aren't looping through the children of .sizeAvail because you didn't directly state though what you did state wasn't in quotes like most aspects of jquery need to be.

If this still does not work make sure you have a jquery library

Or you can use the pure js option:

```
var $items = document.getElementsByClassName('sizeAvail');
var $dur = document.getElementsByClassName('dur');
for (i = 0; i < $dur.length; i++) {
    $dur[i].addEventListener('click', durClick);
}

function durClick() {
    var clickedSize = this.id;
    for (i = 0; i < $items.length; i++) {
        var $liElems = $items[i].getElementsByTagName('li');
        for (i = 0; i < $liElems.length; i++) {
            if ($liElems[i].innerHTML == clickedSize) {
                $liElems[i].parentNode.style.display = 'block';
                $liElems[i].style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                $liElems[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/uZTYf/2/

Comment: As an aside, should use `.prop()` for id.

Comment: You could just do `this.id`

Comment: @PSL: Agreed, `this.id` would be better (leave jQuery out of it). But if you do go to use it, it should be `.prop`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

everything you are trying to do is pretty simple syntax-wise.  you can find documentation on methods to use in a number of places.  you could simply use javascript for this but i am assuming you want to use jQuery

on a high level you'll want to use the jQuery selector to get all UL objects and then for each UL loop over all LI children, e.g.:

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    $(this).find('li').each(function(){

    });
});
```

to get the data you are looking for, you can use jQuery methods like addClass(), attr(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `not`, `has` and `contains` selectors to get the matched elements and set a class on them using `addClass`.

Ref:

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Code:

```
$(".dur").click(function () {
    $(".sizeAvail:not(:has(li:contains('"+$(this).prop("id")+"')))").addClass('hide')
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/t8eMD/

Answer (score 0):

You may use this. Set a flag when checking all li's of a div. If none li has same value as the id, at the end hide the div.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dur").click(function () {
      var clickedSize = this.id;
      $(".sizeAvail").each(function(){
          var hide = 1;
          $(this).children('li').each(function(){
            if(clickedSize == $(this).text()) hide=0;
          });
          if(hide){
              $(this).closest('div').hide(); //Or $(this).parent().hide();
          }
      });
    }); 
  });
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cCgzx/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You may try this too

```
$('a.dur').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    $('ul.sizeAvail li').each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == id) $(this).closest('ul').addClass('hide');
    });
});
```

[**EXAMPLE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/RgHJq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/QyKsb/

This is one way to do it, as you were doing. However, i don't, personally like cluttering html with data as that. But it maybe good choice in some situations but i dont like it.

also you cant give id a value that starts with numbers.

```
var products= $("div[class^='product']"),
    dur =$('.dur');

dur.click(change);
function change(){
   var size= $(this).data('size');
    products.each(function(){
        var d = $(this);
        d.find('.sizeAvail>li').each(function(){
            d.hide(); 
            if($(this).text()==size) { d.show(); return false;}
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: My goodness guys. Being new to this js thing, I'm astounded at how supportive the stackoverflow community is. Thank you all for your input. I'm going to try all of the solutions and see which is best for me. Thank you.